# Pass PHP variable to Modal without AJAX

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table likw so:

```
<table class="table table-striped mb30" id="table1">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Player Name</th>
                    <th>PlayerUID</th>
                    <th>Humanity</th>
                    <th>Alive</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($playerTable)) {
                    echo '
                      <tr>
                        <td>'.$row['characterID'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['PlayerName'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['PlayerUID'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Humanity'].'</td>
                    ';
                    if ($row['Alive'] === '1') {
                      echo '<td>Yes</td>';
                    } else {
                      echo '<td>No</td>';
                    }
                    echo '
                        <td class="table-action">
                          <a href="" id="edit-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                          <a href="" class="delete-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ';
                  }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

When a user clicks `<a href="" id="edit-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>`

they are promted with a modal, now I want to pass $row['characterID'] to the modal, but am having difficulties doing this, could you please suggest a method with a good example that isn't AJAX.

I should mention I want this to be passed in a way that can easily be found using PHP within the modal, i.e $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. Look, PHP runs on the server, clicking happens on the client. By the time you get to the browser, PHP is nothing more than a string of fixed text or tags. If you want to run what's on the server again you can either refresh the screen, go to a new URL or send an ajax query via HttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You could set that ID as another data-attribute.

```
echo '<td class="table-action">
    <a href="" id="edit-row"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"
        data-character-id="' . $row['characterID'] . '">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
</td>';
```

Now you can pass that information into the modal inside the event callback, which handles the anchor-click.